# Request going pending due to threads in WAITING and TIMED_WAITING state

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot

Java spring boot application request goes in pending state as threads held in `WAITING` and `TIMED_WAITING` state.

Jstack logs:

```
"qtp886341817-1399" #1399 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f02142ae800 nid=0x22f904 waiting on condition [0x00007f01c3fa8000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: TIMED_WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000684588e00> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:215)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2078)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.BlockingArrayQueue.poll(BlockingArrayQueue.java:392)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.idleJobPoll(QueuedThreadPool.java:656)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.access$800(QueuedThreadPool.java:49)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:720)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"threadPoolTaskExecutor-1" #114 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f02140b4800 nid=0x229d78 waiting on condition [0x00007f01c55b2000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (parking)
    at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
    - parking to wait for  <0x0000000684588e58> (a java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:175)
    at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2039)
    at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:442)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1074)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1134)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

"qtp886341817-717" #717 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00007f021c102000 nid=0x22c546 in Object.wait() [0x00007f01ee774000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token.waitUntilSent(Token.java:248)
    - locked <0x0000000689516c80> 
(a java.lang.Object) at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttTopic.publish(MqttTopic.java:117)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:364) at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:260) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:305) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:103) at org.eclipse.jetty.io.ChannelEndPoint$2.run(ChannelEndPoint.java:118) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.runTask(EatWhatYouKill.java:333) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.doProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:310) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.tryProduce(EatWhatYouKill.java:168) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.EatWhatYouKill.run(EatWhatYouKill.java:126) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.ReservedThreadExecutor$ReservedThread.run(ReservedThreadExecutor.java:366) at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:765)at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$2.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:683)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Details:

1. In this situation, the application is unable to serve API, the number of current threads went up to 250+, many threads go on deadlock state.
2. This spring application is hosted on AWS's t2.medium instance, Xms=1g, Xmx=2g, UseG1GC and we are using the jetty server.
3. This application generally servers a long thread wait APIs, it takes at least 12 to 60 seconds to respond to some of the APIs.

Questions:

1. Is there any way to find out how much threads can a spring application/JVM/jetty server can handle.
2. How can we tune this application to avoid such a situation (when application non-responsive)
3. How to restrict API's before this hung up situation.

Comment: There's nothing weird about those. The first thread has nothing to do so it's idling for a while, and the second thread is waiting for a task to arrive.

Comment: looks like this is bad application programming and not JVM/Jetty problem. JVM can easily support 10000 threads.

Comment: As the two above me mentioned, I think you have a miss understanding about what is going on here. If a request comes in it will be taken by a thread. That happens very quickly and should not result in `WAITING` or `TIMED_WAITING`. Waiting and timed waiting threads are saying "Hey we are ready to accept requests" and are just idling until a request comes in.

Comment: Please do check the logs for locked thread state also

Answer (score 1):

Look here:

```
at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.Token.waitUntilSent(Token.java:248)
- locked <0x0000000689516c80>
```

there is a lock, happened on timed out attempt to send message. Try to add here an asynchronous call.